# Toolbar back button does not work after rotation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have a single activity application with multiple fragments. I use the `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` in with my fragments. When i navigate trough my app like

> mainView -> fragment 1 -> fragment 2 -> Toolbar back pressed ->
> fragment 1 -> toolbar backpressed -> mainView

there is no problem but if i do an orientation change the back button does not work anymore for fragment 1:

> mainView -> fragment 1 -> fragment 2 -> orientation change -> Toolbar back pressed ->
> fragment 1 -> toolbar backpressed -> nothing happens

in my fragments i set the toolbar in the `onViewCreated` method with

```
val activity: AppCompatActivity? = activity as AppCompatActivity
val toolbar: Toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar)

activity?.setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

activity?.supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
activity?.supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
```

in the mainActivity i handle the clicks with

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> {
            onBackPressed()
            true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount == 0) {
        finish()
    } else {
        hideKeyboard()
        supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
    }
}
```

but it does not get called on fragment 1 after the rotation change

Comment: I would check if activity is null after rotation. so the code activity?.setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

activity?.supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
activity?.supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)

is not executed

Comment: @Rainmaker it is unfortunately not null

Comment: You could add navigationOnclicklistener directly on toolbar inside of oncreate method)) no need in using of setActionBar

Comment: Hi,
Did you find any solution for this, please let me know as am facing a similar issue @tscheppe